# Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

** TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'
** In my browser, there is a issue as above mentioned, I need to get data using formdData

```
methods: {
    getValue(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const form = e.target;
      const formData = new FormData(form); 
      for (const [inputName, value] of formData) {
        console.log({ inputName, value });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Which element has the event handler registered? How does it call `getValue()`?

Comment: As error says - parameter you passed in `FormData` is not a type of `HTMLFormElement`. Looks like `e.target` returning `string`. Hence, it is not accepting by `FormData`. Can you please check.